# get the month last date by adding 6 months to today's date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam adding 6 months to today's date by using below code.

```
var d = new Date();
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 7; //Months are zero based
        if(curr_month<10){
            curr_month = "0"+curr_month;
        }
        if(curr_date<10){
            curr_date = '0'+curr_date;
        }
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        $scope.vmEndDate = curr_year + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_date;
```

When I print $scope.vmEndDate value, Iam getting 2015/09/31 , but in september month 31 day is not there. how to get correct value.

Comment: First you have to decide what the 'correct' value actually is.

Comment: In above code curr_date is today's date(03/31/2015), so when add 6months to this date Iam getting 2015/09/31 , this is wrong date, because 32 day is not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle date with months directly :

```
var today = new Date(2015,03,31)
today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+6)
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString())
```

If you want to get a valid date but in september, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11469976/4682796

Comment: by using above code I am getting the 11/1/2015, 12:00:00 AM, but it showing november month

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript world months begin with zero! kind of weird to me. Anyhow,adding 7 to date is NOT September, but rather 7 is October.

So that means your code is correct

Just change

```
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 7; //Months are zero based
```

to

```
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 6; //Months are zero based
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet might be helpful.

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 6, d.getDate());
console.log(curr_date.getFullYear() + "/" +
((curr_date.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? '0' + 
(curr_date.getMonth() + 1) : (curr_date.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" +
(curr_date.getDate().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + 
(curr_date.getDate()) : (curr_date.getDate())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469917/javascripts-dateobject-jump-from-may-31st-to-next-month-gets-july-1st/11469976#11469976) this can be solved as follows.
You first get the todays date, change its day to first(*or any number which is valid for all months like 1 to 28*), then move ahead by six months and then set the date to last day of the month.

```
function daysInMonth(month, year)
{
    return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
}

var today = new Date()
today.setDate(1)
today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+6)
today.setDate(daysInMonth(today.getMonth(), today.getDate()))
```